# Display text after releasing the Button but after a time delay

Tags: multithreading, button, timer, delay, onlongclicklistener

I want to display the text after releasing the button with a delay 10 seconds. What modifications are to be done.

```
b1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override 
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) 
    {
        t1.setText("Displaying Delay");
        return false; 
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the [public static void sleep (long time)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) Method of the [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread()) class.

> Causes the thread which sent this message to sleep for the given
> interval of time (given in milliseconds). The precision is not
> guaranteed - the Thread may sleep more or less than requested.
>
> **Parameters** time   The time to sleep in milliseconds.
>
> **Throws** InterruptedException    if the current thread has been interrupted. The
> interrupted status of the current thread will be cleared before the
> exception is thrown.

You try something to the extent of:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        t1.setText("Displaying Delay");
        return false;
    } 
    catch(InterruptedException e) {}        
}
```